# How to get the name of a network interface that is down

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, networking, ifconfig

I am using Ubuntu and am just curious as to tell the name of all network interfaces, even the ones I've taken down with **sudo ifconfig wlan0 down** (for example) as they no longer show up in ifconfig.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ifconfig -a` or `ip a l`.

Comment: Thanks... I've used it, but I guess I'm getting slow.

Comment: only `ip a` would suffice..